# HHVM DomDocument loadHTMLFile() not working. BUG?

Tags: php, dom, hhvm

I have this code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$raw = $doc->saveHTML();
```

When I do a `var_dump($raw)` it will show `string(1) " "`. Something is clearly wrong.

A `var_dump($doc)` outputs

```
object(DOMDocument)#5228 (35) {
  ["recover"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["documentURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["strictErrorChecking"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["xmlStandalone"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["standalone"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes"]=>
  NULL
  ["nodeValue"]=>
  NULL
  ["resolveExternals"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["childNodes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["previousSibling"]=>
  NULL
  ["nodeName"]=>
  string(9) "#document"
  ["xmlVersion"]=>
  string(3) "1.0"
  ["lastChild"]=>
  NULL
  ["nodeType"]=>
  int(9)
  ["formatOutput"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["firstChild"]=>
  NULL
  ["parentNode"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownerDocument"]=>
  NULL
  ["config"]=>
  NULL
  ["prefix"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["implementation"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["preserveWhiteSpace"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["documentElement"]=>
  NULL
  ["namespaceURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["baseURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["substituteEntities"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["textContent"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["nextSibling"]=>
  NULL
  ["doctype"]=>
  NULL
  ["validateOnParse"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["version"]=>
  string(3) "1.0"
  ["actualEncoding"]=>
  NULL
  ["encoding"]=>
  NULL
  ["localName"]=>
  NULL
  ["xmlEncoding"]=>
  NULL
}
```

What could be the issue?

**# Update:**

The error is the `loadHTMLFile()`. It returns a FALSE. But why? The path to the file is correct.

If I instead do:

```
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($file));
```

it works just fine. Is that a bug with HHVM?

Comment: Does the thing that does not work in HHVM work fine in a regular PHP environment?

Comment: I do not see  a reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: I think you've missed the point I am making. If it works in regular PHP but not in HHVM, then it may be a bug with HHVM, or a known different behaviour. If on the other hand it doesn't work in PHP either, then perhaps you are doing something wrong. Long story short: it is worth trying it in a regular PHP environment.

Comment: I am sure that it works on a regular PHP as this is not a special code. The same code is listed on the PHP site as an example.

Comment: It might be the case that your HTML has UTF-8 encoding errors in it, and I guess that might also fail with the PHP runtime. Maybe try a simpler, valid document?

Comment: But why does it then work with `$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($file));`? That does not make sense. Also it is a purchased product which is used by thousands of users, so it is extremely unlikely that this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

HHVM (since version 3.3) blocks all external resources by default. Here is an `php.ini` option to enable them again:

```
hhvm.libxml.ext_entity_whitelist = file
```

You can provide multiple stream wrappers using a comma separated list:

```
hhvm.libxml.ext_entity_whitelist = file,http
```

Comment: Thank you. In which file do I need to insert this values?

Comment: It's wherever HHVM's `php.ini` file is. If you're using the prebuilt ubuntu/debian packages, I believe this is at `/etc/hhvm/php.ini`. But it's worth noting this was turned off for security reasons, and you should carefully investigate and evaluate if you want to turn it back on. (I'm not 100% sure of the details, but the issue is similar to some recent Rails vulnerabilities where you could trick it into loading a YAML file and, via some schema loading something, that is equivalent to arbitrary code exec if you aren't careful.)